# Defined variable defined 'within function brackets' is not working in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some div elements in  html file:

```
<div id="pizza1" onclick="galery('pizza1')"></div>
<div id="pizza2" onclick="galery('pizza2')"></div>
```

And I have defined function in external .js file, that's not working (it means it's not doing anything).

```
function galery(var pizza) {
  document.getElementById(pizza).style.left = "10px;";
  document.getElementById(pizza).style.right = "10px;";
  document.getElementById(pizza).style.top = "10px;";
  document.getElementById(pizza).style.bottom = "10px;";
}
```

Is it even possible do something like that in js?

Comment: just `function galerie(pizza){} `, without `var`, also inside event listener you can access element within `this` property

Comment: You are not defining a variable inside the brackets, you're **naming a parameter** than is supposed to be passed to the function. Inside the function, this will work as a variable then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your console you could see the error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

So you've just remove the `var` from the function parameters :

```
function galery(var pizza) {
```

Should be :

```
function galery(pizza) {
```

**NOTE :** Change the `position` to `relative` to see the changes.

Hope this helps.

```js
function galery(pizza) {
  var _this = document.getElementById(pizza);

  _this.style.left = "10px";
  _this.style.right = "10px";
  _this.style.top = "10px";
  _this.style.bottom = "10px";
  _this.style.position = "relative";
}
```

```html
<div id="pizza1" onclick="galery('pizza1')">pizza 1</div>
<div id="pizza2" onclick="galery('pizza2')">pizza 2</div>
```

**Suggested solution `using addEventListener`:**

```js
document.getElementById('pizza1').addEventListener("click", galery, false);
document.getElementById('pizza2').addEventListener("click", galery, false);

function galery() {
  this.style.left = "10px";
  this.style.right = "10px";
  this.style.top = "10px";
  this.style.bottom = "10px";
  this.style.position = "relative";
}
```

```html
<div id="pizza1">pizza 1</div>
<div id="pizza2">pizza 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using bellow code also:

```
<div id="pizza1" onclick="galery(this)"></div>
<div id="pizza2" onclick="galery(this)"></div>

function galery(ctl) {
  ctl.style.left = "10px;";
  ctl.style.right = "10px;";
  ctl.style.top = "10px;";
  ctl.style.bottom = "10px;";
}
```